# Jquery $get with ms-appdata:// prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, win-universal-app

I got html with jquery hosted in my Windows Universal (Windows 10) WebView as Web Hosted App. And I got this issue:

When I'm trying to load a local resource, example :

```
"ms-appdata://local/test.js"
```

from javascript with $get function I am getting network Error on error callback... The main issue is that I am loading the html remotely (my location.href is my server domain)

How can I make it work?

Comment: Try `window.location.href = "ms-appdata://local/test.js"`, used in iPad webview to get resources, don't know whether it'll work for you or try `getScript`

Comment: Can please provide the error you are seeing? I've left my mind reading abilities at the office ;-)

Comment: I've posted the answer... But I didn't get any errors, I've only get the fail promise callback as a result of $.get function

Answer (score 0):

I saw that I have this method in JQuery lib  - **ajaxPrefilter** so I added the library to my script (I know that I've said no libraries - but this one really helped me out)

This is how I've overcame this issue:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
        if (options && options.url) {
            //this is where I can manupulate my url
            //after resolving the requested data I can call options.success event with it
        }
    });
```